# Expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

Before asking the question here, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414287/spring-autowiring-with-unique-beans-spring-expected-single-matching-bean-but-fo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

This is the error I am facing.

```
expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
```

The problem started only after I changed the spring version in my project from 4.1.6.RELEASE to 4.2.5.RELEASE and no change was made to the whole project anywhere.

I am using **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** to print out all the REST end-points in my code. And this is the bean initialisation in my context XML file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
```

Here is the stack trace.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried with @Qualifier but no luck.

When I revert the version to 4.1.6.RELEASE its working fine.

Any help on this is appreciated. I will publish any other details if required.

Comment: Why won't you just use existing bean?

Comment: Do you mean I can Autowire RequestMappingHandlerMapping without declaring this as a bean?

Comment: Yes. Spring mvc declares one

Comment: When I remove the bean declaration from the XML file, I am getting an error saying that not able to autowire because it cannot find a bean of that type. Even if that is the case why is this happening only with the new version?