# Multiple Database connections at runtime using spring -jdbc or hibernate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have one master db. After login with master db I have  some another db. Is it possible to connect at runtime to second db and also have instanace of first db also(master db) application using `spring-jdbc` or hibernate,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. You can create as many data sources as you need. Just define them in the Spring Context and autowire in you classes. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414287) might help you with defining components with the same type but different names.

UPD1: you can create a datasource at runtime just like that:

```
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setUsername("username");
    ds.setPassword("password");
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // or another driver
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://{hostname}:{port}/{dbName}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false");
    ds.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    ds.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    ds.setTestOnReturn(false);
    ds.setValidationQuery("/* ping */ SELECT 1");
    ds.setValidationQueryTimeout(1);
    ds.setValidationInterval(30000);
    ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);        
    ds.setMinIdle(1);
    ds.setMaxWait(10000);        
    ds.setMaxIdle(10);
    ds.setInitialSize(10);
    ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
```

Comment: hi Roman, thanks for reply  i don't  know second database first time .after login master db i know that.