# Spring JPA not connecting to multiple databases: Saying entity managers found 2

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

This is the new file I've added in addition to the existing Persistenceconfig.Java. I'm getting this entity manager as 2 found.

1. we're not using any xml config except for the jpa repositories in spring-data.xml
2. The issues is occuring only for one package created newly for logging activity and that is also included in jpa repository.

### Before adding the below class, everything is normal previously

```
package com.jumbotree.kumcha.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
//import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
//@PropertySource("classpath:kumcha.properties")
@PropertySource("file:/opt/jumbotree/kumcha2/kms.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.jumbotree.kumcha.crm.model", entityManagerFactoryRef = "createEntityManagerFactoryChargingBean", transactionManagerRef = "createChargingTransactionManagerBean")
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-data.xml")
public class ChargingPersistenceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChargingPersistenceConfig.class);


    @Bean  
    public DataSource createChargingDataSourceBean() {
        LOGGER.info("Charging Datasource created...");
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("charging.db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("charging.db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("charging.db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("charging.db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    //Here is the entity manager added and causing this issue
    @Bean   //(name = "entityManagerFactoryCharging")
    @PersistenceContext (unitName="chargingPU")
    public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> createChargingEntityManagerFactoryBean(@Qualifier("createChargingDataSourceBean") DataSource dsc) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean chargingentityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        LOGGER.info("Charging entityman created...");
        try {
            chargingentityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(createChargingDataSourceBean());
            chargingentityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.jumbotree.kumcha.crm.model");
            chargingentityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(createJpaVendorAdapterBean());
            chargingentityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(createJpaProperties());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            LOGGER.error(e.toString());
        }


        return chargingentityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties createJpaProperties() {
        LOGGER.info("hibernate.show_sql :::: "+env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        return new Properties() {
            {
//                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
                setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
               // setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
               // setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
               // setProperty("shared-cache-mode", "DISABLE_SELECTIVE");
                //<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
                //setProperty("hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior", "convertToNull");
            }
        };
    }

    private JpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapterBean() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
//        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.valueOf(env.getProperty("db.name")));
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
//        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean   //(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager createChargingTransactionManagerBean() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Charging transactionMan created...");
        JpaTransactionManager chargingtransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        chargingtransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(createChargingEntityManagerFactoryBean(createChargingDataSourceBean()).getObject());
        return chargingtransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor createPersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    // Required if using Hibernate 4
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslator createPersistenceExceptionTranslatorBeaan() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8414287/1531971

Comment: Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi All, I've added the complete class of new persistenceconfig I tried to create for new DB connection. Now there are two persistenceconfig files each datasource trying to create connection with db's on different IP's

Answer (score 3):

`LoggerRepository` cannot choose one of the 2 beans `createChargingEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `createEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Make one of them primary and/or specify qualifier. (BTW sometimes even with qualifier it's necessary to make one of beans primary)

Cannot suggest cconfig changes without your code.

Comment: Thanks StanislavL..I've added @Primary for the first persistence bean config.Still didn't work.