# Spring boot @EnableAsync & @EnableScheduling No qualifying bean Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

im working in spring project and this my code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class ApeApiApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApeApiApplication.class, args);
  }

}

@Component
MyServiceOne {

 @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${scheduler.delay}")
void myMethod {

     }
}


@Service
MyServiceTwo {

 @Async
void myMethod {

     }
}
```

but im getting the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: applicationTaskExecutor,taskScheduler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.getDefaultExecutor(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:233)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.getDefaultExecutor(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$configure$2(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:119)
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.determineAsyncExecutor(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.invoke(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at fr.bpifrance.bae.ape.application.invoice.InvoiceApplicationService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f545fb55.printInvoices(<generated>)
    at fr.bpifrance.bae.ape.api.invoice.InvoiceController.printInvoices(InvoiceController.java:178)
    at fr.bpifrance.bae.ape.api.invoice.InvoiceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c0bc9a1a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at fr.bpifrance.bae.ape.api.invoice.InvoiceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8beeb05.printInvoices(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1449)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

when i call my `@Async` method

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem that you have described. Can you share the complete stack trace of the error and, ideally, a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414287/spring-autowiring-with-unique-beans-spring-expected-single-matching-bean-but-fo

Comment: @AndyWilkinson i added the whole stack trace. there no specific example to reproduce, im just calling my Asyn void method and it triggers the exception. thanks

Comment: Are you only seeing the exception in debug logging? If so, it can be ignored. `AsyncExecutionAspectSupport` catches `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`, logs it at debug level and then uses the bean named `taskExecutor`.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson you are right the exception is triggred only in debug mode. so you confirm that i can ignore it and no action to do from my side ?

Comment: @James Confirmed. The exception is benign (that's why it's only logged at debug level) and can be ignored.