# Controller spring bean share property and reference bean causes javax.servlet.UnavailableException

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans containing the same property name and reference bean, could this be causing my error?:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler x to URL path /path There is already handler of type [class myclass] mapped.
```

Code:

```
<bean name="bean1"
    class="myclass1">
    <property name="property">
        <ref bean="ref" />
    </property>
</bean>



<bean name="bean2"
    class="myclass2">
    <property name="property">
        <ref bean="ref" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I can't seem to trace my error anywhere else. Please comment if you need more information.

Edit: The console prints the error is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler`

I also have another exception: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed`

Comment: The spring configuration you have posted is unlikely to cause any problems. Do you have any controllers in your application that handle `/path`?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802293/spring-beancreationexception-confusion-about-mapping

Comment: @geoand there is only one controller handling /path, which is why I am confused why it says it is already handled?

Comment: @Prasad I already looked at that and do not have that problem.

Comment: @JordanD Perhaps a Clean Compile will help

Comment: @geoand it worked the first time I tried it but the error has returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing all of:

```
<bean name="bean2"
    class="myclass2">
    <property name="property">
        <ref bean="ref" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

And my controller started mapping correctly.